Is there a way to get a css grid to auto add a col when image reaches max-width?
I have a grid. Each cell will be an image with a max-width (used simple colored div in ex). Is there a way to have the grid automatically add another column when the images reach their max-width instead of just increasing the gap between them. (same for removing a column when shrink to min-width). Here is the sample code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <style>
      .pet-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        gap: 10px;
        width: 100vw;
      }

      .pet {
        aspect-ratio: 1/1;
        background-color: cadetblue;
        max-width: 205px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header></header>

    <main>
      <div class="pet-grid">
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>


I think this might be what you are looking for. The idea here is to calculate the number of columns based on a maximum column width much like auto-fit does. but round the column number up when the available width is between the multiples of the cell's maximum width instead of down.
To do this we need to divide the viewport width by the cell's maximum width, and to do this, this answer leans heavily on the information provided in the article CSS Type Casting to Numeric: tan(atan2()) Scalars by Jane Ori.
Here we define a custom property "--1mcw" to mean 1 <main> element content box width.
To calculate the target number of columns, we take the main element content box width and divide it by the sum of the maximum width of a cell and the width of the gap. However we add one gap width to the main element content box width because the grid will have one fewer gaps than columns. Then we round it up to the nearest integer.
The final calculation looks like this:
main {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.pet-grid {
  --1mcw: 100cqw;
  --gap: 10px;
  --max-width: 205px;
  --target-columns: calc(round(up, tan(atan2(var(--1mcw) + var(--gap), 
                                   var(--max-width) + var(--gap))), 1));
}

Then the cells will grow up to a width of 205px, and then add another column, reducing the cell width down to match.
This is a bit new and a bit hacky. It seems to work in Chrome and Firefox, but I haven't tried it on Safari.


@property --1mcw {
  syntax: "<length>";
  initial-value: 0px;
  inherits: false;
}

main {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.pet-grid {
  --1mcw: 100cqw;
  --gap: 10px;
  --max-width: 205px;
  --target-columns: calc(round(up, tan(atan2(var(--1mcw) + var(--gap), var(--max-width) + var(--gap))), 1));
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--target-columns), 1fr);
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.pet {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header></header>

    <main>
      <div class="pet-grid">
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>




Updated as per Temani Afif's suggestion in the comments to use the cqw units of the main element rather than the viewport, so that the presence or absence of the vertical scrollbar is accounted for in the available width.

maybe make the main a container and rely on cqw?

@TemaniAfif - Yes, I was just considering that. I'll look into that later.

Fancy, but not very didactic. This is not a hackaton.

@NVRM it's not fancy but the new era of CSS. That's how we will be writing CSS in the future. People are still no ready for this but they will be sooner or later.

Use grid-template-columnswith auto-fill or auto-fit
https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/

auto-fill FILLS the row with as many columns as it can fit. So it creates implicit columns whenever a new column can fit, because it’s trying to FILL the row with as many columns as it can. The newly added columns can and may be empty, but they will still occupy a designated space in the row.
auto-fit FITS the CURRENTLY AVAILABLE columns into the space by expanding them so that they take up any available space. The browser does that after FILLING that extra space with extra columns (as with auto-fill ) and then collapsing the empty ones.



.pet-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto,205px));
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.pet {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  max-width: 205px;
}
<main>
  <div class="pet-grid">
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
  </div>
</main>




Hi Paulie, not quite what I want. Doing that locks the size to 250px... I want the images to grow UNTIL they reach 250px...but dont want them a fixed size.

The principal is the same, grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto,205px)); might be what you are after. The idea is that you don't specify a number of columns, you let the browser choose.

Still not quite. What's happening is that once the max width is reached, they stay that width when new columns are added. What I would like is for when they exceed max-width 205px a new column appears but the images then resize to accommodate the new space (they should shrink in size, then when they again reach max-width .. the process repeats. Instead .. the new column is remaining empty until another max-width image can fit ... not what I would like. Hope that was clear .. if not let me know.

That makes no sense. If they reach a max-size, why would they shrink again? There is no CSS property that can do that, certainly not in CSS-Grid. Maybe flexbox but I doubt it.
